# Why do I get memory errors in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, pagefile

Sometimes I run multiple heavy applications simultaneously, for example, Adobe After Effects and various 3D render engines. Sometimes while they are running at the same time, one of them will fail with an "Out of Memory" error, referring to RAM (not GPU VRAM). Given that Windows has a pagefile, shouldn't the excess memory needed be written to disk instead of failing altogether? When resources are limited, I thought anything else that there wasn't room for in memory would go on disk rather than the program failing entirely. Am I wrong?

The 64-bit Windows 10 machine has 64 GB of RAM. After Effects uses as much ram as the system has available. The program running out of memory is returning an internal memory error (not a Windows memory error). The pagefile is "system managed" with a minimum of 16MB with a recommended of 9080MB. The currently allocated is 29977MB.

Comment: There is a limit to the size of the page file.  How do you know you aren't hitting that limit?

Comment: I have not seen a memory error since Windows XP. How much memory do you have?  How big is your page file - It should be set to automatic.

Comment: There are three types of memory. Physical memory, virtual memory, and VM address space. I'll give stats for 32 bit programs. From a program's perspective only address space matters. There is 4 GB of address space for the program. 2 GB for system DLLs etc and 2 GB for program code and data. So you can only use 2 GB **per program**. The system 2GB only one physical copy of the system dlls are in memory but appears in each program.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more information about the amount of physical memory you have in the system and how large your page file is exactly

Comment: @Ramhound, I have edited the question.

Comment: I have reviewed your edits. Maybe try repairing the heavy duty Apps and then restart to see if that makes any change.

Comment: @John, is it possible the program is checking the available memory capacity and deciding to quit because there isn't enough available?

Comment: I have not seen that in modern programs. All the ones I use can manage memory cooperatively with Windows. Make sure the apps are the newest versions.  You can also use Admin Tools Resource Monitor, enable the memory line, let it run for 20 minutes and see what is going on.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 - No; The error dialogue your getting, based on the description, is a Windows error dialogue indicating you have ran out of virtual memory. There is something absolutely wrong with your configuration it’s just not clear what that is

Comment: How much space is left on the drive? Is Adobe using the same drive as scratch disk?